# Django: view arguments after POST?

Tags: python, django

I call my "editFamily" view via an HttpResponseRedirect from somewhere else:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('editFamily', kwargs={'pk': family_id}))
```

The corresponding url pattern looks like this:

```
url(r'^editFamily/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.editFamily, name='editFamily')
```

And then finally there's my view:

```
def editFamily(request, pk_):

    obj = models.Family.objects.all().filter(pk=pk_)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.FamilyForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = forms.FamilyForm(instance=obj)

    return render(request, 'editFamily.html', {'form': form})
```

It takes the pk_, ends up in the else branch and serves my edit-html. But what happens after the viewer submits his data with respect to the argument pk_? Is pk_ missing when I'm coming from POST? Do I somehow have to make sure to pass that argument in my template?

Comment: Why are you using pk_ ? Use pk instead.

Comment: because of "filter(pk=pk)" ... looked weird to me and I wanted to avoid errors.

Comment: but your variable should match up with what you have used in urls.py file. You can use  `url(r'^editFamily/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.editFamily, name='editFamily')` and then  `def editFamily(request,id):`

Comment: @user3182532: filter(pk=pk) is completely idiomatic though, it won't give errors.

Comment: okay, then I'll go back to pk=pk :)

Comment: @user3182532 See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it wouldn't be missing. The form is submitted to the same page, so the URL remains the same and the arguments are still present.

Comment: okay thanks! I didn't find that topic covered in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanted to use some other variable than pk. Lets use variable `id` for your convenience
Change urls.py to

```
 url(r'^editFamily/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.editFamily, name='editFamily')
```

And in the views.py you can access the variable from the url path as

```
def editFamily(request, id):
    obj = models.Family.objects.all().filter(pk=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.FamilyForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = forms.FamilyForm(instance=obj)

    return render(request, 'editFamily.html', {'form': form})
```

It is important to use same name in urls.py and views.py so that the view function can pick the variable from its url path by name.

Comment: thanks for the hint, you're right. I get errors if urls.py and views.py don't match with regard to argument names